# How to access html select option value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the value of `option 3` in select name `period` with jQuery?

In Javascript, I use `document.form.period.value` to access the value when button is clicked

```
<form name="form">
<select name="link">
  <option value="1">$1000</option>
  <option value="2">$2000</option>
  <option value="3">$3000</option>
  <option value="4">$4000</option>
  <option value="5">$5000</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.form.link.value)" value="alert">

<select name="period">
  <option value="1">1 day</option>
  <option value="2">2 day</option>
  <option value="3">3 day</option>
  <option value="4">4 day</option>
  <option value="5">5 day</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.form.period.value)" value="alert">
</form>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Do you want "selected value" or "third option value"?

Answer (score 3):

I am ashamed to answer this question, but:

```
$('select[name="period"] > option:nth-child(3)') // get the third option element
$('[name="period"]').val() // get the value of the selected option
```

Comment: Oh my... Why? Why not `val`?

Comment: "I am ashamed to answer this question" is the best part of this answer. It doesn't do what the OP wants. He wants to access the selected value not just the 3rd one.

Comment: OP didn't say that it will be the selected option

Comment: + 1 This is almost bang on, just missing the val(). Can't believe it was down voted so fast

Comment: @YuryTarabanko if you use `.val` it will return the value of the selected element. This guy wants to get the value of the third option, not the value of the selected option.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the question is poorly phrased, since the OP specifically said he returns the value of the `period` element (i.e. the selected option) and _not_ that of the "third option element".

Comment: @MarcoBonelli according to `document.form.period.value` it is that what OP wants :)

Comment: The answer gets the third option. The question was how do I get the value of the third option. Why the question was asked in the first place I don't know

Comment: "How do I get the value of option 3 in select name period with jQuery?" what else does this mean if it doesn't mean "i want the value of option 3 in select period"????

Comment: Can't believe you got down voted Marco :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused lol, idk why people should vote me down or vote down this question. Everyone has been a newbie, me too. So if the OP doesn't know how to do it why shouldn't we answer him?